При подключении сетевого моста в Oracle VM VirtualBox интернет-соединение не работает
До этого использовал NAT, выход в интернет был. Но понадобился удаленный запуск на сервере, который будет запускаться на ВМ.
В качестве виртуальной машины стоит Linux Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (64-bit)
Пытаюсь настроить подключение для удаленного запуска тестов на виртуальной машине. Посмотрев кучу гайдов, не выделил чего-то, что может отличаться от текущей конфигурации. Все всегла все устанавливают по дефолту. А за изменение сетевых конфигов, к сожалению, не шарю от слова совсем. Если нужна какая-то дополнительная информация, пишите.




Т.е. у тебя в хостовой ОС пропадает интерент? Я правильно понял?

не, в хосте все работает. не работает в ВМ. по итогу я пока сделал 2 адаптера - NAT и host-only. пинговать могу в обе стороны теперь. Но bridge по-прежнему не работает

А хост как интернет получает? Роутер есть? Или ты статику на компе настраивал?

Через напрямую подключенный кабель, без роутера. Ничего дополнительно не настраивал

Т.е. шнур от провайдера заходит сразу из подъезда к тебе в комп?
